# Ruby on Rails Application and Mongrel Failing to Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I have a Ruby on Rails (Rails v2.0.2) application which I have developed using Netbeans 6.1 on Mac OS X.

When I tried to run this application this evening (it was working fine this morning) I get the error:

'could not connect to the web server - cannot show http://localhost:3000'

When I try to run the application from terminal using: ./script/server

I get the following error:

=> Booting Mongrel (use 'script/server webrick' to force WEBrick)
=> Rails application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3000
** Starting Rails with development environment...
nil
Exiting

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Walter

Comment: Just curious; is there any reason you're not using Passenger? (http://modrails.com/) I gave up Mongrel long ago...

Comment: Hi neezer. Do you think that Passnger would solve this issue?

Comment: Well, Passenger is just an alternate method of serving your app, so it wouldn't "solve" your issues with Mongrel; you'd use it in place of Mongrel. If you're on a Mac, there's even a preference pane that makes this setup dead-easy (http://www.fngtps.com/2008/06/putting-the-pane-back-into-deployment).

Comment: Ahh, you are on a Mac. Should have re-read the question. :)

Comment: Hi neezer.  Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: You should try seeing if you can get your rails application to work in Passenger. If it does, then you know the issue is with Mongrel; if not, then you probably have an error somewhere in your Rails App that's causing Mongrel to crash. Try to isolate the problem, you know? Have you done any recent upgrades?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is enough info here to correctly diagnose the issue.

You could try running it with debugging: `ruby -d ./script/server`. You will probably find an exception being raised shortly before it exits. With a bit of luck the exception will make sense to you.

If that fails, try and narrow the problem scope by running a simple task (`rake -T` or `./script/runner 'puts "OK"'`).

Worst case, try starting it up with a full debugger and set a breakpoint on `NilClass#to_str` / `#to_s`. That pesky `nil` in your output is the only clue I can see.

Comment: I know this is not really an answer, but I needed more space and formatting than the comments allow.

Comment: For the record, I never claimed that passenger would fix anything; just that it would be helpful in determining if the problem lay in Mongrel or in his application code.

Comment: Sorry, did not intend to imply that. Amended.